# When running commands with && how can I keep it running when one command fails?

Tags: command-line, bash, error-handling

For example I have a `.gitconfig` for one project, since I do a lot of code reviews, that reads:

```
review = "!f(){ git checkout master && git pull origin master && git branch -D $1 && git fetch && git checkout $1 && git pull origin $1 && bundle install && rake db:migrate && git checkout -f; };f"
```

Now I know it's a little overkill and I don't need it all but I like it that way. It makes me feel like the review branch is totally clean. Sometimes it's nice to see the message `Already up-to-date.`

Now when the branch does not exist yet then `git branch -D $1` will fail and it throws an error and doesn't run the rest of the commands.

Is there a way that I can make the rest of the commands run even if one of the commands fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the whole point of `&&` - ensuring that the previous command succeeded before running the next. If you don't need that, use `;` instead. The following will echo `foo`:

```
false; echo foo
```

And the following won't:

```
false && echo foo
```

See Bash manual, section [List of Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists-of-Commands):

> Commands separated by a ‘`;`’ are executed sequentially; the shell
>   waits for each command to terminate in turn. The return status is the
>   exit status of the last command executed.
>
> AND and OR lists are sequences of one or more pipelines separated by
>   the control operators ‘`&&`’ and ‘`||`’, respectively. AND and OR
>   lists are executed with left associativity.
>
> An AND list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 && command2
> ```
>
> `command2` is executed if, and only if, `command1` returns an exit
>   status of zero.
>
> An OR list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 || command2
> ```
>
> `command2` is executed if, and only if, `command1` returns a non-zero
>   exit status.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just replace `&&` with `;`.

The command after `;` will run regardless of the exit status of the command before `;`.

Comment: They will still run in succession? And only run once the last completes?

Comment: @user974407 Yes..they will..

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `&&` as this means only complete this command if the previous command completed successfully.

Use `;` instead, it's comparable to a new line, and is not dependent on the exit status of the previous commands.